# Extract year from a string using PHP regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I want to extract year from a string. I got an incomplete solution. My string will be always like:

> Please message mpg of jazz 2014 and 2015+ to my mobile number 
>   +123456789

I have tried the following regex;

```
preg_match_all('!\d{4}+| \d{4}+\W!', $str, $matches);
```

This will output the following array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  2015 
            [1] =>  2014+
            [2] => 1234
            [3] => 5678
        )

)
```

I need to get only the year portion with + symbol if any. I.e, i want only this:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] =>  2015 
                [1] =>  2014+                
            )

    )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `\d{4}+| \d{4}+\W` pattern matches either 4 digits (note that the possessive `{4}+` quantifier equals `{4}`) or a space, 4 digits, and any non-word char.

You may use

```
'~\b\d{4}\b\+?~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ndi6PI/1)

**Details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `\d{4}` - 4 digits
- `\b` - another word boundary
- `\+?` - an optional (1 or 0 occurrences) plus symbols.

[PHP demo](https://ideone.com/dsB23P):

```
$re = '~\b\d{4}\b\+?~';
$str = 'Please message mpg of jazz 2014 and 2015+ to my mobile number +123456789';
if (preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches[0]);
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2014
    [1] => 2015+
)
```

Comment: Thank you. It helped me to get years from string

Comment: @PawanThakur You might also use `\b(?:20|19)\d{2}\b` to only extract contemporary years.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  But I am happy with the above code because I hade array like array('03/2016','1995','2002 4th Series','2003/2004','04/1991','12/2009','06/1977 - 311XXXX','04/2008','02/1999 T series','06/1995 N159XXX'); and I got perfect years from $matches[0][0]. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Matching dates (4 digits), optionally followed by a `+`, between spaces:

```
preg_match_all('( [0-9]{4}\+? )', $str, $matches);

echo '<pre>' . print_r($matches[0], true) . '</pre>';
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  2014 
    [1] =>  2015+ 
)
```