# Regular Expressions - Extracting Years

Tags: python, regex, expression

I am trying to extract dates from a string. I have come up with a solution, however, it isn't very glamourous. Could anybody share a better alternative?

[image]

Comment: Maybe `\b(?:20|19)\d{2}\b`?

Comment: See [Extract year from a string using PHP regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51653030/extract-year-from-a-string-using-php-regex)

Comment: Please don't show code or data in pictures. The contents cannot be cut and pasted and links have a tendency to break over time. Also, if the string were `"2019 and 2020"` what would be desired result?

Answer (score 0):

If your date format is same as per above pattern then following regex will work:

```
(?:\b\d{4}\b\s*,*\s*)+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this  `\b\d{4}(?:\s*,\s*\d{4})*\b`

- \b - word boundary
- \d{4} - 4 digits
- \b - another word boundary
- \s,\s - another space , space
- *- quantifier

Comment: Please can you add more details in your answer?

Comment: Add detils work now ? see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51653030/extract-year-from-a-string-using-php-regex

Comment: Thanks, is easier to understand that way